# Devise, Rails 4 and routing error

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I got a strange error with my rails 4.0.0 app with devise 3.1.1 when launching server or rake routes

```
Rails::Application::RoutesReloader#execute_if_updated delegated to updater.execute_if_updated, but updater is nil: 
# <Rails::Application::RoutesReloader:0x000000044f5e80 
@paths=["/opt/web/devise/config/routes.rb"], 
@route_sets=[#<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x000000045ce190>]>
```

My routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :path => "/", :path_names => { 
  :sign_in => "signin", 
  :sign_out => "signout", 
  :sign_up => "signup"
}
```

My application_controler.rb

```
before_filter :configure_strong_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
...
protected
  def configure_strong_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :gender, :name, :lastname, :birthday, :country
  end
```

My users_controler.rb

```
private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:pseudo, :email, :gender, :name, :lastname, :birthday, :password, :password_confirmation, :country)
  end
```

My User.rb

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

I try to remove the gem, remove devise.rb initializer and reinstall it, no changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

I was running into this issue today. Rails 4.0.0 and devise 3.10.

The problem started when I added to the User.rb in the model. Apparently, you have the leave the devise generated stuff at the top and alone, and put whatever changes you want BELOW that or else you will get this error.

If this doesn't work try regenerating the user.rb by using the `rails g devise User` again and then leaving the default stuff alone at the top and then placing whatever new code you want **below** that.

BTW, the default should look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

***Put your code here***
end
```